Sending commands to an opened link in Selenium with Python
I am trying to write a code that will go to a web page with links, search though each link by element, click on the link and then save it.
So far I have managed to find the link that I want and click on it. I am trying to send the keys CTRL + S and ENTER, but I keep getting error.
Error Details:
File "c:\Users\Victor\Desktop\Selenium\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    open_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "s")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Here's what I have so far:
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.examtopics.com/discussions/comptia/94/")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

search = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "CAS-004")
open_link= search.click()
open_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "s")
open_link.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

I feel like I'm almost there but I'm stuck at this point.

From your code, you open a new page when you do "open_link= search.click()". then the "search" will no longer exist. also the "open_link" isn't the next page. you need to "find_element" with new locator to find the element, the do "send_keys" to the new element.  you can add more details for what you want. I don't know what you want to do in next step exactly.

so the process is:
1)open driver to webpage
2)find element with link and click on it (will open a new page)
3)send keys ctrl + s to open up the save as dialogue
4) send keys ENTER to save the page

Do you need to save the page or need to save the page content? If you need to save the HTML then you can just write the driver.page_source to a file and save it as HTML.

So what I had to do to send the commands was the following:
import pyautogui

#sends ctrl + s
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')

#presses enter
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.press('enter')

